# Login window within the parent window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am currently programming web application but I am still a beginner, so I don't know the exact term for what I am asking for.

I want my login window to as the following:

if the user clicks on Login button a window will appear in the same page that the user currently viewing and it won't go away until user close it or login.
similar to message box in twitter.

is there a way to do that in php or javascript? and how to do it?

- I can't post picture yet :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery Dialog to create a login dialog in where you ask the user for his credentials.

But yes it can be created with javascript.

Take a look for jQuery UI

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple idea. Obviously you can play around with the functionality and styles. This is just a quick guideline.

```
$('#loginButton').click(function(){
    $('body').append('<div id="overlay"></div><div id="login"><form><h1>Your form</h1></form></div>');
    $('#login,#overlay').hide().fadeIn();
});
```

CSS

```
#overlay{
    positon:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    content:"";
    z-index:1001;
    background:#000000;//for ie add an opacity
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
#login{
    background:#FFFFFF;
    border-radius:8px;
    position:fixed;
    top:40%;
    max-height:60%;
    width:auto;
    min-width:20%;
    margin:0% 40%;
    z-index:1002;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #333333;
}
```